# EmberJs input onkeypress event not sent to component

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using EmberJS and I want that when the user types a key in my search bar, that an action is sent to my component. I have read (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextSupport.html#property_onEvent) that I should put the **onEvent="keyPress"** in my input but it doesn't work. Currently, if I type some text, the `search()` method is not called, but it is if I press enter.

Here is my template:

```
<div id="command-manager">
    {{input type="search" action="search" onEvent="keyPress" placeholder="Enter a command here" maxlength="32"}}
</div>
```

Here is my component:

```
var CommandManagerComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  actions:{
    search:function() {

      console.log('search');

    }
  }
});
```

As you can see, this is pretty straightforward, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using ember-cli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://emberjs.com/guides/components/sending-actions-from-components-to-your-application/

> In general, you should think of component actions as translating a
>   primitive event (like a mouse click or an  element's pause
>   event) into actions that have semantic meaning in your application.

Otherwise use a view, for UI transitions/effects.

Now, to use actions with your component you need to use `sendAction()`.

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wofom/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. The component versus view thing can be tricky.

I found extending a helper was the quickest method. Try this:

```
var CommandManager = Ember.TextField.extend({
    keyUp: function ( event ) {
        // targetObject is the active view controller
        // this function will look for the search action
        // on your controller
        this.get('targetObject').send('search');
    }
});
Ember.Handlebars.helper('command-manager', CommandManager);
```

You can call this in your template like so:

```
<div id="command-manager">
    {{command-manager placeholder="Enter a command here" maxlength="32"}}
</div>
```

**Notes**

1. This will input a standard text input not a *search* input, is that
   ok?
2. I'm assuming you're using a controller, if you're not then remove
   the `this.get('targetObject').send('search');` part and run your
   code in the `keyUp` function.

I hope that helps. Good luck!